# Casting problems with Google Maps API

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying to run the following line:

```
Directions.loadFromWaypoints((Waypoint[])waypoints.toArray(), opts);
```

But I'm getting:

```
23:41:44.595 [ERROR] [carathome] Uncaught exception escaped
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.google.gwt.maps.client.geocode.Waypoint;
    at com.presasystems.gwt.carathome.client.widgets.MostrarLinhasPanel$1$1.onSuccess(MostrarLinhasPanel.java:72)
    at com.presasystems.gwt.carathome.client.widgets.MostrarLinhasPanel$1$1.onSuccess(MostrarLinhasPanel.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why? Shouldn't this cast work? How can I do this in an elegant fashion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Directions.loadFromWaypoints((Waypoint[])(waypoints.toArray()), opts);
```

Alternatively

```
Waypoint[] array = new Waypoint[0];
array = waypoints.toArray(array);
Directions.loadFromWaypoints(array, opts);
```

Or more simply

```
Waypoint[] array = waypoints.toArray(new Waypoint[0]);
Directions.loadFromWaypoints(array, opts);
```

See also [`List#toArray(T[] a)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29).

Addendum: Initially, I thought your cast was a precedence problem. The generic parameter `T` in [`List#toArray(T[] a)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) eliminates the need for an explicit cast by ensuring that the "runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array." In effect, it "acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs."

Comment: Can you post a link to the API?

Comment: What's the declaration of `waypoints`, and what new error are you getting?

Comment: ArrayList<Waypoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<Waypoint>();

Error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.google.gwt.maps.client.geocode.Waypoint;

Comment: This looks like the same exception; you might try the other `toArray()` method of `List`.

Comment: It is the same. I don't see how List would solve the problem, because it is an interface. It would actually do the exactly same thing. But your array proposal is right. I was just wondering what's wrong with the code I posted.

Comment: I would advocate coding to the interface. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html

Comment: I agree, but that's not what I asked.